# How to make d3 sub elements stick to the top-right corner or main SVG

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

I have a following d3 javascript function to draw a drawing. I want the subelements to stick to the top-right corner of the main element ** First "rect"** when the element is resized. Since SVG can't be nested in one another, how can I make them stick to the top right corner of the "rect" element.

```
BusinessInteractionFigure.prototype.paint = function(g) {
g.attr('data', 'BusinessInteractionFigure');
// main element
g.append('rect')
 .attr('x', Figure.OFFSET)
.attr('y', Figure.OFFSET)
.attr('rx', 12)
.attr('ry', 12)
.attr('width', 100%)
.attr('height',100%)
.attr('stroke', 'rgb(178,178,126)')
.attr('stroke-width', 1)
.attr('fill', 'rgb(255,255,181)');
// arc 1 (right)
g.append("path")
.attr("d", "M 115,10 A 5,5, 0, 1, 1, 115,20")
.attr("fill", "none")
.attr("stroke","black")
.attr("stroke-width",1);
// line 1 (right)
g.append("line")
.attr("x1",115)
.attr("y1",10)
.attr("x2",115)
.attr("y2",20)
.attr("stroke","black")
.attr("stroke-width",1);
// arc 2 (left)
g.append("path")
.attr("d", "M 112,10 A 5,5, 0, 0, 0, 112,20")
.attr("fill", "none")
.attr("stroke","black")
.attr("stroke-width",1);
// line 2 (left)
g.append("line")
.attr("x1",112)
.attr("y1",10)
.attr("x2",112)
.attr("y2",20)
.attr("stroke","black")
.attr("stroke-width",1);
};
```

Maybe the X and Y value of each of the sub elements needs to be set in a way that whenever "rect" is resized. the sub elements still stick to the top-right of the element.

How it looks before resizing:

[image]

How it looks after resizing:

[image]

Comment: This post seems to cover the scenario you describe:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/6322799/3063063
Your d3 usage isn't necessarily further complicating things, as it appears you are simply using it to manipulate the DOM.

Comment: Or just write javascript code that repositions the svg graphics based on the known new width. Since it looks like those graphics are all inside a single `<g>`, you should move the entire group with a single attribute: `transform="translate(...)"`

Comment: Who says svg can't be nested?