# svg resize not working on chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I've got a svg element that I want to be on top right, and full height until the width allows it, then I want it to be full width.
I've written this, and it is working on firefox and edge, but not on chrome.

```css
header{
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
#logoSvg{
    max-height: 100vh;
    width: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
}
```

```html
    <header>    
    <svg id="logoSvg" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
                  viewBox="0 0 762.3 762.6" style="enable-background:new 0 0 762.3 762.6;" xml:space="preserve">
            
        <path d="M0-0.6v0.9l762.3,762.3V-0.6H0z M572.8,375.9c-57.6,6.8-120.5,7.5-189.8,7.5V0c68.9,0,132.2,0.8,189.8,7.5c110.7,13.2,189.1,67.8,189.1,183.8C761.9,308.1,683.6,362.7,572.8,375.9z"/>
    </svg>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To align the SVG's children to the top-right, you need to use `preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMax meet"`. This process is described in the question [How to align an object in SVG document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517979/how-to-align-an-object-in-svg-document?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

```css
header{
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
#logoSvg{
    max-height: 100vh;
    width: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
}
```

```html
    <header>    
    <svg id="logoSvg" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
                  viewBox="0 0 762.3 762.6" style="enable-background:new 0 0 762.3 762.6;" xml:space="preserve" preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMin meet">
            
        <path d="M0-0.6v0.9l762.3,762.3V-0.6H0z M572.8,375.9c-57.6,6.8-120.5,7.5-189.8,7.5V0c68.9,0,132.2,0.8,189.8,7.5c110.7,13.2,189.1,67.8,189.1,183.8C761.9,308.1,683.6,362.7,572.8,375.9z"/>
    </svg>
</header>
```